# How to handle Zim Error "The ZIM tree pool has overflowed"

Tags: zim-database

I have the following code:

```
set output spoole

select * from displays where displayname='dsp020a'
select * from forms where formname in (select formname from displayforms where displayname='dsp020a')
select * from formfields where formname in (select formname from displayforms where displayname='dsp020a')
```

The third select is crashing ZIM with the following error:

`*** ZIM System Error *** The Zim tree pool has overflowed. Type BYE to exit from Zim.`

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to use SQL in ZIM, I also saw problems and unexpected errors. You should always try to use the native ZIM 4GL commands to access data as well as object definitions.

ZIM Data Dictionary contains some predefined internal relations which can help analyse the data model. For example, you could say:

```
list all Displays DispDispForms DisplayForms where Displays.DisplayName = "dsp020a"
```

to find out which forms are contained in the given display. Likewise you could do:

```
list all Forms FormFormFields FormFields where Forms.FormName in ("f020a", "f020b", "f020c")
```

to list all form fields which belong to the given forms. Unfortunately, there is no relation between DisplayForms and Forms, so you cannot achieve directly what you tried in your example using SQL.

OR (added after your comment):

You can achieve that using a small program. For this example, it would be:

```
set output output_file
find Displays DispDispForms DisplayForms where Displays.DisplayName = "dsp020a"
while $setcount > 0
    let vStr = DisplayForms.FormName
    list all Forms FormFormFields FormFields where Forms.FormName = vStr
    let $setcount = $setcount - 1
    next
endwhile
set output terminal
```

Now you have all form fields which belong to all forms of the given display listed in the output_file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Too bad I can't retrieve all the form fields used on some display with ZIM. I was trying to create tools to analyze some legacy code in order to identify dependencies between programs, entities and displays.

Comment: Thank you Milan. I tried your code and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There probably already is a relationship between dfs and forms in the db schema but the documentation is poor.  However, you can create your own.  Note that dfs is a role for displayforms.

> add 1 rels let relname = 'dfsforms' relcondition = 'dfs.formname = forms.formname' reltype = 'ZIM' dirname = 'ZIM'
>
> create rel dfsforms

Now you can find forms related to displays using:

> find all displays dispdispforms dfs dfsforms forms formformformfields wh displays.displayname = 'dsp020a'